# help with laplace

Tags: laplace-transform

I have to get to the second part of the ecuation with laplace and I don't know how to do it step by step, help please! thanks!!

$$\int\limits_{-\infty }^{+\infty }{\left( \frac{\sin x}{x} \right)^{3}dx}=2\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty }{\frac{x^{2}}{2}\cdot \frac{6}{\left( x^{2}+1 \right)\left( x^{2}+9 \right)}dx}$$

Comment: Welcome to Math SE ! What have you tried ? More precisely, where do you get stuck ?

Comment: hello! thanks!!the real thing is that in order to solve the problem I have to do it with jordan, because I have to solve it using complex variables, but to use that method I have to change it with Laplace first, and a friend of mine showed me the result but not the steps to get to that result and personally I dont know much about laplace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind that the Laplace transform takes the following form:

$$F(s)= \int_{0}^{\infty} f(x) e^{-sx}dx. $$

Let us make use of the following set of properties :

$$ \begin{align}
 \int_0^\infty F(u)g(u) \, du  & = \int_0^\infty f(u)G(u) \, du \\[6pt]
 L[f(t)] & = F(s) \\[6pt]
 L[g(t)] & = G(s)\end{align} $$

Let

$$ G(x)=\frac{1}{x^3} \implies g(x)=\frac{x^2}{2}, $$

so

$$ f(x)= \sin(x)^3  \implies F(x) = {\frac {6}{ \left( {x}^{2}+1 \right)  \left( {x}^{2}+9 \right) }}. $$

Putting those together and considering our function is even, we get:

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin^3 x}{x^3}= 2\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin^3 x}{x^3} \, dx = 2\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty }{\frac{x^{2}}{2}\cdot \frac{6}{\left( x^{2}+1 \right)\left( x^{2}+9 \right)}dx} $$.

Comment: thanks!! I undestand how I get to that answer, but I dont understand step by step how to do $$G(x)=\frac{1}{x^3} \implies g(x)=\frac{x^2}{2}$$ or $$f(x)= \sin(x)^3  \implies F(x) = {\frac {6}{ \left( {x}^{2}+1 \right)  \left( {x}^{2}+9 \right) }}$$